# Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT error when appending values into a Double Array

Tags: ios, swift, yql, finance

I'm trying to get stock performance data from the past year and past six months. While I've used a similar YQL data-pull in other parts of my app (they work fine), this particular attempt causes a Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT error to appear. When debugging, I can see that the NSArray 'quote' contains all the values that I'm trying to use. I've been struggling to find a reason for this error, so any help will be appreciated. My code from the function is below.

```
func getData() -> (Dictionary<String, Double>, Dictionary<String, Double>) {

    let queries = ["XLY", "XLP", "XLE", "XLFS", "XLF", "XLV", "XLI", "XLB", "XLK", "XLU"]
    var performance1YearDictionary : Dictionary<String, Double> = Dictionary()
    var performance6MonthsDictionary : Dictionary<String, Double> = Dictionary()
    var pricesArray = [Double]()
    var yearAgoPrice = Double()
    var todayPrice = Double()
    var sixMonthsAgoPrice = Double()
    var performance1Year = Double()
    var performance6Months = Double()

    let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components([.Day , .Month , .Year], fromDate: date)

    let year =  components.year
    let month = components.month
    let day = components.day

    let dateString = "\(year)-\(month)-\(day)"
    let dateString2 = "\(year - 1)-\(month)-\(day)"

    for var stock in queries {

        let query = "select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = '\(stock)' and startDate = '\(dateString2)' and endDate = '\(dateString)'"

        let results = YQL.query(query)
        let quote = results["query"]!["results"]!!["quote"]!! as! NSArray

        for var i in 0...252 {
            pricesArray.append(quote[i]["Close"] as! Double) //line that causes SIGABRT error
        }

        yearAgoPrice = pricesArray[252]
        todayPrice = pricesArray[0]
        sixMonthsAgoPrice = pricesArray[126]

        performance1Year = (todayPrice - yearAgoPrice) / yearAgoPrice
        performance6Months = (todayPrice - sixMonthsAgoPrice) / sixMonthsAgoPrice

        performance1YearDictionary[stock] = performance1Year
        performance6MonthsDictionary[stock] = performance6Months

    }

    return (performance1YearDictionary, performance6MonthsDictionary)

}
```

Comment: Well, a `quote` is a `NSArray` right?, what objects does it store? Show me example of that object with its properties if any.

Comment: I think I found my mistake. The error stemmed from your question - it seems like the objects in the NSArray were strings, so my attempt to append them to a [Double] naturally didn't work. Once I made the appropriate changes, the code is now executing without error. However, I am now receiving a Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT error in the AppDelegate, even though all of my connections are correct (I've checked them multiple times). I expect that I will be able to figure out this new issue soon, but for the time being, this current issue is solved. Thanks for your help!